# Autoscroll Sidebar Item

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, sidebar, autoscroll

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm am relatively new to JavaScript programming, so I ask please for your patience.

I've put together [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/chris/test.php) page, which allows users to add or remove Google Map markers via 'Marker Category' check box selection. In addition to the relevant markers being added and removed from the map, the description for each marker is added or removed from a 'Sidebar; which is shown in orange text.

If the user clicks on the 'Sidebar' item, the info window for the relevant marker will be displayed, and if the marker is selected, the relevant description in the sidebar listing will be highlighted with a grey background.

The problem I have is if a user selects a marker on the map the sidebar doesn't automatically scroll to the item relevant list item as shown in the example on [this](http://www.blocsoft.com/bmap/example12.V3.asp) page.

I am using a third party script to create the scroll bar which is shown in the code below:

```
<script>
        (function($){
            $(window).load(function(){
                $("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar({
                    scrollButtons:{
                        enable:true
                    }
                });
                //ajax demo fn
                $("a[rel='load-content']").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $this=$(this),
                        url=$this.attr("href");
                    $.get(url,function(data){
                        $("#sidebar .mCSB_container").html(data); //load new content inside .mCSB_container
                        $("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar("update"); //update scrollbar according to newly loaded content
                        $("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo","top"); //scroll to top
                    });
                });
                $("a[rel='append-content']").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $this=$(this),
                        url=$this.attr("href");
                    $.get(url,function(data){
                        $("#sidebar .mCSB_container").append(data); //append new content inside .mCSB_container
                        $("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar("update"); //update scrollbar according to newly appended content
                    });
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
</script>
```

and this is the section of code that links the map marker and sidebar item.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
  infowindow.setContent(contentString);
  $("#sidebar a").css('background-color','');//remove sidebar links back colors
  sidebarlink = $("#sidebar a:contains('"+marker.mydescription+"')");
  sidebarlink.css('background-color','#DADADA');
  infowindow.open(map,marker); 
});
```

I have tried to put a `overflow` item in both areas, hoping that this would solve the problem. In addition, I've also omitted the following lines to see whether I could come up with a solution:

```
$("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar("update"); //update scrollbar according to newly loaded content                          
$("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo","top"); //scroll to top
```

Unfortunately my attempts haven't solved the issue.

I just wondered whether someone may be able to look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: It would help if you had a link to your site

Comment: Hi @davidstrachan, thank you very much for taking the time to reply to my post. My apologies if I didn't make this clear in my original post. But I did provide a link to the page in question, but please find this link again. http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/chris/test.php
Many thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following line, to your marker click event handler:

```
$("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo","a:contains('"+marker.mydescription+"')");
```

so your code would look like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
  infowindow.setContent(contentString);
  $("#sidebar a").css('background-color','');//remove sidebar links back colors
  sidebarlink = $("#sidebar a:contains('"+marker.mydescription+"')");
  sidebarlink.css('background-color','#DADADA');
  $("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo","a:contains('"+marker.mydescription+"')");
  infowindow.open(map,marker); 
});
```

that should scroll to your clicked item.

Comment: Hi @Nelson, I really can't express how appreciative I am for this. It's absolutely amazing, and a huge weight off my mind. You are most deserved of the bounty and when the time limit elapses I shall award you this. Many thanks for all your time trouble and effort. Kind regards

Comment: Thanks @IRHM , I'm happy I could help with your problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding one line to your event handler function:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
//......
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition()); // <---Add this line
  infowindow.open(map,marker); 
});
```

Comment: Hi @Marcelo, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post an offer a solution. Unfortunately, although I've added the code you suggest. This does not solve the problem. I've run the code through JavaScript Console and unfortunately there is no error shown which may have pinpointed where the problem was. Many thanks and kind regards.